# how to use javascript to detect whether a web page is responsive on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design

I need to use javascript to detect whether a page is responsive. On a galaxy note 3, here are the values for a non-responsive and a responsive pages:

```
non-responsive: 
window.innerWidth:980 
clientWidth:980 
screen.width:640 

responsive: 
window.innerWidth:640 
clientWidth:640 
screen.width:640
```

So is it correct to say that if `clientWidth == screen.width` then it is responsive, else it is non-responsive?

Comment: Nope. That just means the page is zoomed in or out.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, there's an important feature used in responsive design call media query, with which browser can switch alternative CSS rules for different screen resolutions to make page "responsive".

You can enum CSS rules in Javascript using `document.styleSheets`. And CSS like

```
@media all and (max-width:1023px) {
    /* some styles */
}
```

will add some instances of CSSMediaRule in cssRules collection. Here's my detection code. Works in Chrome and Safari.

```
function isResponsive() {
  if (document.styleSheets || (typeof window.CSSMediaRule).match(/function|object/)) {
    // find avaliable style sheets
    return [].some.call(document.styleSheets, function(css) {
      if (!css.cssRules) {
        return false;
      }

      // find avaliable rules
      return [].some.call(css.cssRules, function(rule) {
        if (rule instanceof CSSMediaRule) {
          return [].some.call(rule.media, function(media) {
            return !media.match(/print/i);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
  // There's no avaliable style sheet, or the browser doesn't support media queries
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Cool.. Thanks! :) Just need to add `if (r == null) continue;` after `r = s[i].cssRules;`

Comment: Nice script but note it won't pick up any cross domain CSS files (e.g. those served by a CDN) so isn't entirely accurate. Also, you might want to check if the media rule isn't a `@media print` rule, as they have nothing to do with how responsive a page is.

Comment: @RobCampo `@media print` is now excluded

Comment: this now just gives exception when there is cross origin css