# Determine if a site is responsive on mobile using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

**What are the best ways to determine if a site is responsive or not using JavaScript?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717056/how-to-use-javascript-to-detect-whether-a-web-page-is-responsive-on-mobile) details checking for `@media` queries, which is somewhat accurate. However checking `@media` queries may not always work because:

a) A responsive site doesn't necessarily need media queries (e.g. they may sniff the user agent and produce different HTML based on it)

b) The media query might only influence a small part of the page (e.g. the footer)

Maybe comparing HTML from different user agents would give a good indication also? Or checking the size of the media query content (e.g. if it's large, it might effect a large part of the page).

Comment: Open it up in a device? Have the browser spoof the device?

Comment: Using JavaScript though. I.e. programmatically. (description did state, subject updated now also)

Comment: So you want to somehow feed content fetched from some URL into a JavaScript program, and have it spit out either RESPONSIVE or NOT RESPONSIVE?  Seems like the first problem is determining an objective definition for "responsive".

Comment: @Pointy exactly. The definition of responsive in this case is a site that works well on mobile. E.g. is easily readable, no horizontal scrolling etc.

Comment: Making a piece of software determine whether a site "works well" seems pretty hard.  (Horizontal scrolling is not *necessarily* bad, for example; it completely depends on how the site is designed.)

Comment: Great question. To clarify, this would be JavaScript running in the browser? In which case, could there be an `<iframe>` in the document into which the web page to test is loaded? I'm thinking of using JavaScript to check to the horizontal overflow of the iframe's content. If there's no overflow on an iframe that is, say, 320px wide, that would be a good test that the website is optimised for mobile, at least.

Comment: you can always run the speed of reading the website on the mobile device

Comment: Why are you doing this? There are plenty of sites out there that already offer this kind of thing. Here's a link to Google's: https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Comment: @K.P. yep, running in the browser. That might work but some pages scale correctly but aren't responsive.

Comment: @diggersworld Nice tool but how do they determine a site is responsive? Would be nice to be able to write a script that checks. Haven't found a great solution so opening to see if others have thoughts.

Comment: @RobCampo by "running in a browser" I hope you mean as some sort of browser extension. Browsers won't let code in a page look at the contents of an `<iframe>` containing content from a different domain.

Comment: @RobCampo This is such as interesting challenge. But I think we will need to define what we mean by "responsive". We'd need to come up with a specific test. I'd say any web page that does not have significant horizontal overflow at a variety of screen widths starting from 320px can be said to be responsive. Now, theoretically you could have a fluid one-column layout that scales perfectly for every device, but doesn't use a single media query. In my mind, that's still a "responsive" site. What do you think?

Comment: @K.P. Technically a pure HTML site is responsive, e.g: http://info.cern.ch/

Comment: @diggersworld Agreed, totally. And that would fit my criteria: no horizontal overflow at almost any screen size.

Comment: @K.P. think you're on to something there alright. Maybe the question is how to determine when a site isn't responsive. A site that overflows on a screen width of 320px likely isn't responsive. The solution may be to assume responsiveness first off, then look for traits that make it unresponsive.

Comment: Agree @diggersworld also, info.cern.ch is in my eyes a responsive site. It works perfectly fine on mobile without scrolling issues etc.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest tip in the HTML to tell if a website is some how responsive would be the meta viewport (it is used to control layout on mobile browsers). It doesn't mean the site works correctly in different browser size/devices.

You can check it with.

```
if(document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"][content*="width=device-width"]') !== null){
     //if is true do something
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But I'd want to check that the `viewport` meta tag's value contains this specific string: "width=device-width".

Comment: If the HTML documents loads any CSS, you might also want to parse that and check usage of `@viewport`. This will replace the viewport meta tag, eventually. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport

Comment: @K.P I changed the code to check for "width=device-width"

Comment: Thanks @CarlaFrança, this is definitely a contributing factor in determining responsiveness. Sites without this could probably be deemed not responsive. Problem is some sites may have this but not be responsive.

Comment: @CarlaFrança how about this to check for meta viewport with `width=device-width` instead?

`document.querySelectorAll('head meta[name="viewport"][content*="width=device-width"]').length > 0`

Comment: That would work fine but for efficiency I would use (document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"][content*="width=device-width"]') !== null ) it will look for the first element within the document that matches the selectors and stop. The querySelectorAll will keep checking for more.

Comment: @CarlaFrança good point. Want to update the answer?